# Rails 3.1 - Inheriting values from a join table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following models: `Releases`, `Tracks` & a `has_many` join called `ReleasesTrack`.

I also have `Product`s that (semi) successfully inherit a releases tracks with Track & Release Ids being copied to a `ProductsTrack` has_many_through join.

The problem is i'm not getting the correct position value.

I currently have this in `ProductsTrack` model, it appears to work, but i'm not getting the value I want.

```
 before_save do
     self.position = self.track.position
 end
```

Instead of the position value in the track table, I want the position from it's has_many_through join table releases_tracks. I've tried the following a variations thereof, but no joy:

```
 before_save do
    self.position = self.track.releases_track.position
 end
```

I did think having a position field in both Tracks & ReleasesTracks could be causing the issue and there is a reason I have this in both, but I've tested with a temp field and it's not that.

I think the crux of the issue is structring `self.track.releases_track.position` correctly.

OR

I'm missing something in an association?

Any ideas?

EDIT: MODELS ADDED (Note, ProductsTrack is actually the badly named Producttracklisting)

```
class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy

  has_many :releases_tracks, :dependent => :destroy, :after_add => :position_track
  has_many :tracks, :through => :releases_tracks, :order => "releases_tracks.position"

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tracks, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => :true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :releases_tracks

  def position_track(track) 
   releases_tracks.each { |t| t.position = t.track.position }
  end

  def track_attributes=(track_attributes)
    track_attributes.each do |attributes|
    tracks.build(attributes)
    artists_tracks.build(attributes)
    end
  end 
end

class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :releases_tracks, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :releases, :through => :releases_tracks

  has_many :producttracklistings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :products, :through => :producttracklistings  
end

class ReleasesTrack < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :release
  belongs_to :track   
end

class Producttracklisting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :track

  before_save do
     self.position = self.track.position
  end
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :release
  has_many :releases_tracks, :through => :release, :source => :tracks      

  has_many :producttracklistings, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tracks, :through => :producttracklistings

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tracks, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? }, :allow_destroy => :true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :producttracklistings

  #Below is where a product inherits tracks from the parent release
  before_save do
    self.track_ids = self.releases_track_ids 
  end          
end
```

Comment: Add the definitions of your models, it is hard to keep in mind your models.

Answer (score 0):

> I have the following models; Releases, Tracks & a has_many_through join called ReleasesTrack

So you have

```
class Release < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :release_tracks
  has_many :tracks, :through => :release_tracks
end

class Track < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :release_tracks
  has_many :releases, :through => :release_tracks
end

class ReleaseTrack < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :release
  belongs_to :track
end
```

> I also have Products that (semi) successfully inherit a releases tracks with Track & Release Ids being copied to a ProductsTrack has_many_through join.

```
class Products < ReleaseTrack
  #uses table release_tracks
  #belongs_to :release #from inheritance
  #belongs_to :track #from inheritance
end
```

> I currently have this in ProductsTrack model, it appears to work, but i'm not getting the value I want.

*What ProductsTrack model?*  Did you mean before that you have a ProductsTrack that inherits from a release tracks?

```
class ProductsTrack < ReleaseTrack
  #uses table release_tracks
  #belongs_to :release #from inheritance
  #belongs_to :track #from inheritance

  before_save do
    self.position = self.track.position
  end
end
```

> Instead of the position value in the track table, I want the position from it's has_many_through join table releases_tracks.

So far, the way I've coded it base on what you said, self.position *is* the position from the has_many_through join table release_tracks.

Comment: I suspect his Product inherits from Release.

Comment: Wow, Marlin thanks for going to so much effort here! I've added my models to the original question, @Salil is correct, a Product inherits tracks from it's parent Release.....with it's own join table to enable tracklisting variations basically. For example Product A & B will inherit the parent Release tracks, but we might decide B should have a bonus track and then we also later need Product C that's a sampler with only a small selection of the parent release tracks etc etc.

Comment: Kind of my point of writing it all out was there was confusion in his description about the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Your data model probably needs to be cleaned up.  It's probably way more complicated than you need, but, given the model, let's sort things out.

1. There is no inheritance.  All the record models inherit from ActiveRecord::Base.
2. You basically have releases, tracks, and products with a many-to-many relationship between releases and tracks, and another many-to-many relationship between tracks and products.
3. Also, products belongs_to releases and products has_many :releases_tracks through it's release.

Your question is

> I currently have this in ProductsTrack model, it appears to work, but i'm not getting the value I want.

> Instead of the position value in the track table, I want the position from it's has_many_through join table releases_tracks.

You do not list a ProductsTrack model, so I assume this is the Producttracklisting class.  You want to set the position field in the producttracklistings table to "*the position from it's* has_many_through join table releases_tracks".

So the answer is that you cannot do this, because there is not one release_tracks record for the given producttracklistings record.  The producttracklistings points to a (belongs_to) a tracks record, but the releases_tracks records point to the tracks record (not the other way around), so there can be any number of release_tracks records from 0 to many, which your question refers to.

Comment: Yes, it has evolved into a bit of a monster! Inheritance may have been bad wording, upon product create the release track ids are copied to producttracklisting (which i'd prefer to be called ProductsTrack) with the line `self.track_ids = self.releases_track_ids` , it's really something like this I want, something that will just copy that position value from the ReleasesTrack model. If an entry in that model has release_id / track_id / position I don't see why it's not possible?

Comment: Just a further thought; it must be looking at the ReleasesTrack model on Product create to know which tracks to copy across right?

Comment: Suppose track with id = 1 and product with id = 2 are linked in producttracklistings with id = 12.  Lets say that release with id = 3 and release with id = 4 are linked to track 1, with releases_tracks records 13 and 14 respectively, and have positions 5 and 6 respectively.  Which release_tracks record should be used?  This is going to determine whether the position is 5 or 6.  You cannot set the position in producttracklistings to both 5 and 6!